# Syntax error on token "implements", extends expected

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

I just started on Java and when i tried to put implements in my test code on eclipse, this error came up: "Syntax error on token "implements", extends expected". Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: This means you either try and "implements" an abstract class, or you try and program an interface reusing another (in that case use "extends")

Comment: thank you, it seems i was trying to use implement on an interface instead of a class

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an interface and can extend a non-final class. It seems you are using the implements keyword for a class  instead of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Correct:

```
class ClassName implements InterfaceName1, InterfaceName2, ..., InterfaceNameN {} 
class ClassNameA extends ClassNameB {}
interface InterfaceNameA extends InterfaceNameB {}
```

Not correct, extends is expected:

```
interface InterfaceNameA implements InterfaceNameB {}
```